# How to plot with 2 grouping variables in R?

Tags: r, plot

How can I plot this in R with Department and Year grouped, with Time as x-axis and Counts as y-axis? And have a line connecting and colors the same groups

```
  Department  Year Counts  Time
1        CPD  2011     24   0
2        CPD  2011     28   1
3        CPD  2011     31   2
4        APD  2012     20   0
5        APD  2012     25   2
6        APD  2012     21   3
7        CPD  2012     30   2
8        CPD  2012     26   3
9        CPD  2012     11   5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this...

```
library(ggplot2) 
df$depYr <- paste(df$Department,df$Year,sep="_") #set a combined dept_year variable
ggplot(df,aes(x=Time,y=Counts,colour=depYr,group=depYr))+geom_line()
```

[image]